# Image Button how to go back previous image on second click(asp.net,vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I click on red seat, I want it go back to previous image which is blue seat.

[image]

The code in asp;

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="s12" ImageUrl="~/Images/available_seat_img.gif" OnClick= "s12_Click" runat="server" />12
```

And this is in my page load in the code behind;

```
Protected Sub s12_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles s12.Click

    Dim available = "~/Images/available_seat_img.gif"
    Dim booked = "~/images/booked_seat_img.gif"

    If s12.ImageUrl = available Then
        s12.ImageUrl = booked
    Else
        s12.ImageUrl = available
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please Describe what is the exact problem you are facing. What is not working ?

Comment: Hi @Malcor  I want go back to previous image,that's not working...

Comment: HI @SuperPeanut  I want go back to previous image,that's not working...

Comment: It works for me. Is there anything else going on with the `ImageUrl` in your code? If you set the initial image in the `Page_Load` event handler, make sure that you do it inside an `If Not IsPostBack` conditional block.